# Configurando um DSN via Código C#

Tags: c#, odbc

Olá achei esse artigo falando como fazer  Configurando um DSN via Código em VB. Há como fazer o mesmo em C# para um conexão com BD Mysql? Obrigado...
[VB -   Configurando um DSN via Código](http://www.macoratti.net/vb_dsnc1.htm)

Comment: Esta solução do `SOen` te ajuda? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/334939/how-do-i-create-an-odbc-dsn-entry-using-c

Comment: @FelipeDouradinho já havia visto esse post, mas não consegui fazer. ele não cia nenhuma conexão